# React App Deployed on Vercel Only Displays Content from index.html, Missing Full App Functionality

Tags: reactjs, typescript, deployment, vercel

I've deployed my React application on Vercel, but when I visit the deployed site, it only shows the plain text from my index.html file ("hello world from paris !") instead of the full functionality of my React app that I see on localhost:3000. I'm having trouble understanding why the full application isn't being rendered.

Here are the details of my setup and what I've checked so far:

**Project Structure:** My project is a standard React application created using create-react-app. The source TypeScript files like App.tsx and colors.tsx are in the src directory.

**Build Process:** Running npm run build or yarn build locally generates the build directory successfully with index.html, JavaScript, and CSS files.

**index.html File:** The index.html in my build folder looks correct and includes links to the JavaScript and CSS files. Here's the content of my index.html in VS Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <!-- Meta tags, links to CSS, and other head elements -->
</head>
<body>
   <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
   <div id="root"></div>
   <script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.fb7ea4a7.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's the content of my index.html in my github repo:

```
hello world from paris !
```

4. **Vercel Deployment:** The repository is connected to Vercel, and the deployments are being triggered on each push. The build process on Vercel doesn't show any errors, and the deployment is marked as successful.
5. **Issue:** Despite the successful deployment, visiting https://myapp.vercel.app/ only shows the text "hello world from paris !" (which is part of the index.html), but none of the React components are rendered.
6. **Attempted Solutions:** Checked for JavaScript errors in the browser console on the deployed site but found none. Ensured that the paths to assets and scripts in index.html are correct. Tried clearing the browser cache and accessing the site in incognito mode.
   Reviewed Vercel deployment settings for any misconfigurations.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Why isn't my React application rendering as it does locally? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!